# Skipping to next step in Batch program

Tags: batch-file

```
    @echo off
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    color b
    goto play

    :play
    cls
    set name2= OoggieBoogie
    echo Hello, My name is !name2!^^! I'm an AI. I'm here to help with your lazy 
    Butt :D^^!
     timeout /t 3 >null

echo!name2!: May I Have Your Have Your Name Please? :)
color c
echo (Pssst^^! Want to cut the Bullshit and go straight in? Select "Express" please!)
timeout /t 2 >null
echo A. My name is 
echo B. Express
set /p input=
if !input! equ B goto Writing2


cls
echo!name2!: Hello !name!, Shall we continue now?
echo 1.Yes :D
echo 2.No  -_-" ..
set /p input=!name!:
if !input! equ 1 goto Writing
if !input! equ Yes goto Writing
if !input! equ 2 exit
if !input! equ No exit



:Writing2
echo Okay.. Whatever you want Damn.. I was trying to be nice ^^!
echo Anyway. Inatiating EXPRESS Route----->
goto Writing
```

Hello!
What I am trying to do here is skipping all the steps and go straight to "Writting2" if typed Express.

I am almost done with this fun program but I can't figure out a good way skip all the steps.
When I type "Express or select 'B'
it crashes.
but If I write a name the program works as usual!

Thanks in Advance!
Sorry in Advance if I did something wrong in the community.

Comment: If you open a Command Prompt and enter `Color /?`, you'll notice that the correct syntax involves both foreground and background colours! The recommended syntax for the `Set` command is `Set "VariableName=VariableValue"`. There's no need for delayed expansion, so remove that, revert to `%VariableName%`, and drop your incorrect use of escape carets. It's `Nul` not `Null` and there should be a space, _or other character_, after `Echo`. You should use `Choice` instead of `Set /P`, _this would mean that you could remove the incorrect use of `Equ` instead of `==`_.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way you can do what you want:

```
@echo off
color b
goto play

:play
cls
set name2= OoggieBoogie
echo Hello, My name is %name2% I'm an AI. I'm here to help with your lazy 
::echo Butt :D^^!
timeout /t 3 >nul

echo %name2%: May I Have Your Have Your Name Please? :)
color c
echo (Pssst^^! Want to cut the Bullshit and go straight in? Select "Express" please!)
timeout /t 2 >nul
echo A. My name is 
echo B. Express
choice /c:AB>NUL
if errorlevel 2  goto Writing2
set /p "name=Enter your name: "

:Writing
cls
echo %name2%: Hello %name%, Shall we continue now?
echo 1.Yes :D
echo 2.No  -_-" ..
choice /c:1Y2N>NUL
if errorlevel 4  goto exit
if errorlevel 3  goto exit
if errorlevel 2  goto Writing
if errorlevel 1  goto Writing


:Writing2
echo Okay.. Whatever you want Damn.. I was trying to be nice ^^!
echo Anyway. Inatiating EXPRESS Route-----^>
goto Writing

:exit
exit /b
```

Remember: Variables can be accessed by `%variable_name%` and you can set them by `set "variable_name=variable_value"` as @Compo mentioned above.
It is better to use `choice /c` option in your future batchfiles. A disadvantage of this option is that you cannot enter a string with more than 1 character, but it does it's own errorhandling, so you don't have to deal with invalid responses. Also, when you write

```
echo Anyway. Initiating EXPRESS Route----->
```

`>` symbol causes problems as it is a redirection character and should be escaped:

```
echo Anyway. Initiating EXPRESS Route-----^>
```